# Grab the number after Strong tag Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

```
  <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; border: none;">
    <strong>test:</strong> 62
  </td>

  <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; border: none;">
    <a style="color: inherit;" href="redacted">
      <strong>test:</strong> 51
    </a>
  </td>

  <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; border: none;">
    <a style="color: inherit;" href="redacted">
      <strongtest:</strong> 11
    </a>
  </td>
```

I want to grab the number after each strong tag. I figured I could do doc.select("strong ~ *") but that is giving me null.

I've also tried
Element strong = document.select("strong").first(); //shouldn't this be the first element after the strong tag or is between?

What's the answer to select AFTER a closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers you are looking for are not between the strong tags. They are either inside the td tags or inside an a tag which itself is inside a td tag. You can get the numbers by selecting the td tags and checking if the td has its own text; if yes that is your number else get the first child of the td which is the a tag and get its own text. Example:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupTest {
    public static void main(String argv[]){
        String html = "<table>"+
                    "  <td style=\"padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; border: none;\">" +
                    "    <strong>test:</strong> 62" +
                    "  </td>" +
                    "  <td style=\"padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; border: none;\">" +
                    "    <a style=\"color: inherit;\" href=\"redacted\">" +
                    "      <strong>test:</strong> 51" +
                    "    </a>" +
                    "  </td>" +
                    "  <td style=\"padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; border: none;\">" +
                    "    <a style=\"color: inherit;\" href=\"redacted\">" +
                    "      <strong>test:</strong> 11" +
                    "    </a>" +
                    "  </td>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements tds = doc.select("td");
        for(Element e : tds){
            if (!e.ownText().isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(e.ownText());
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(e.child(0).ownText());
            }
        }           
    } 
}
```

Comment: Wow I really overlooked that. Thank you. I knew about how Jsoup handles text with nodes, but for some reason I kept using strong when td will also grab the text.